# SIM5320 CELL LOCATION

Tags: gps, location, command, cell, at-command

i've been trying to develop a project taht uses gps and cell location with SIM5320A, i have successfully implement the GPS location, but when i try to use the AT commands related to the Cell location the SIM responses with an error message, for that reason i bougth a FONA 3g to make some tests with the cell location, but im algo getting error messages.

Hope you can help me with that
thank you

`
at
OK
at+cpin=0000
OK

+STIN: 25

+STIN: 25

+CPIN: READY
a
SMS DONE

+VOICEMAIL: INIT_STATE, 0, 0
a
PB DONE

START
at+cassistloc?
ERROR
AT+ CASSISTLOCTRYTIMES=3,2
ERROR
`

UPDATE

I've seen in some forums taht some AT doesnt work depending on the firmware version, mine is 1575B12SIM5320A , should i update to the last one?

Comment: Could you show us these error messages?

Comment: AT+CASSISTLOCMODE=1
ERROR
AT+ CASSISTLOCTRYTIMES=3,2
ERROR
AT+CASSISTLOC=?
ERROR